# Por que me sale [object HTMLCollection]

Tags: javascript, map

Hola buenas tardes amigos quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar:
EN TOTAL TENGO 3 TABLAS (en la imagen está expresado con T1,T2 y T3)
Con la función MAP de javascript recorro el arreglo de objetos de la primera y segunda tabla, lo que quiero hacer es juntar esos resultados (T1 Y T2) en la tabla número 3.
En el código podrán ver que en la función "Obtener datos tabla" es en donde quisiera realizar el map de ambas tablas para después jalar variables y listo.
Pero parece que la variable "nolotes" no funciona como debería de ser.

Les enseño el código y los resultados:

TABLA 1:

```
  <table id="example1" width="100">
                    <tr onmouseover="this.className = 'resaltar'">
                      <th>Id</th>
                      <th>Nombre</th>
                      <th>Cantidad de lotes</th>
                      <tbody >
                  
                      @foreach($ruta as $r)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$r->idr}}</td>
                        <td name="nombre" id="nombre">{{$r->productos->nombre}}</td>
                        
                        <td><input class='form-control' type="number" id="txt-cant"> 
                        </td>
                   </table>
```

TABLA 2:

```
   <table id="example1.5" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Producto</th>
                      <th>No.Lote</th>  
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody name="listaElementos1.5" id="listaElementos1.5" >
                      
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
```

DATOS NO.LOTE:

```
 function noLotes(){
    
    document.getElementById('listaElementos1.5').innerHTML = '';

    //función que itera el array de objetos que proviene de los elementos seleccionados de la tabla 1 
    $('#example1 tr').map(function(){
      
      let nombre=$(this).find('#nombre').eq(0).text(); 
      let cantidad=$(this).find('#txt-cant').val();
    
    //ciclo que coloca el nombre del producto segun la cantidad de lotes seleccionada
      for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {  
      document.getElementById('listaElementos1.5').innerHTML +=
       "<td>"+nombre +"</td>"+
       //DE AQUI SACO LA INFO DE LOTES
       "<td><input  class=form-control type=text id=nolote></td>" 
      
     }

    });
```

Función:

```
function obtenerDatosTabla(){
      document.getElementById('listaElementos2').innerHTML = '';

       $('#example1.5 tr').map(function(){
        let nolote=$(this).find('#nolote').eq(0).text(); 

        });
 
   

    $('#example1 tr').map(function(){
      
    let nombre=$(this).find('#nombre').eq(0).text(); 
    let cantidad=$(this).find('#txt-cant').val();

     if(F1<=F2){
     for (var i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {  
    ORDER= new Maquina1(nombre,F1, M1,nolote,horai,dora);
   agregar()
     }
    });


    function agregar(){
      var cadena = '';
      document.getElementById('listaElementos2').innerHTML = cadena;
      basedeDatos.push(ORDER);
         data.forEach(maquina => {
          cadena += '<tr>'
          cadena += '<td>' + [j] + '</td>' 
          cadena += '<td>' + maquina.nombre + '</td>'
          cadena += '<td>' + maquina.nolote + '</td>'
          cadena += '</tr>'
          
        })
      }
```

RESULTADOS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]